# python iterator skip_func

Tags: python, iterator, generator, skip

```
def yield_and_skip(iterable,skip):
    for i in iterable:
        print(skip(i))
        for x in range(skip(i)):
            pass
        yield i
```

I'm defning a function called skip_yield, which produces a value from the iterable but then it then skips the number of values specified when the function argument is called on the just-produced value. It takes 2 parameters: skip is a small function.
However, if I try to do this:

```
print(''.join([v for v in yield_and_skip('abbabxcabbcaccabb',lambda x : {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}.get(x,0))]))
```

it gives me:

```
abbabcabbcaccabb
```

but it should give me:

```
abxccab
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's the point of having a loop with empty body (`pass`) here?

Comment: Can you please share the yield_and_skip function?

Comment: Please don't deface your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `pass` doesn't do anything to `iterable`. If you need to advance the iterator, call the `next` function on iterator object `skip(i)` number of times (either directly or indirectly).

Also, `next` call may raise `StopIteration`, thus terminating the loop. `yield i` before advancing the iterator **or** provide the second argument, to make `next` swallow the exception.

Your code would look like

```
def yield_and_skip(iterable, skip):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for i in it:
        for _ in range(skip(i)):
            next(it, None)
        yield i
```

Comment: "yield i before advancing the iterator" is not necessary and `next(it)` should be `next(it, None)`

Answer (score 2):

You could define a counter for the number of elements to skip and update it accordingly

```
def yield_and_skip(iterable,skip):
    num_to_skip = 0
    for i in iterable:
        if num_to_skip == 0:
            num_to_skip = skip(i)
            yield i
        else:
            num_to_skip -= 1
```

The output of your sample line is

```
>>> print(''.join([v for v in yield_and_skip('abbabxcabbcaccabb',lambda x : {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}.get(x,0))]))
abxccab
```